# Does 11.2 dm3 of nitrogen consist of 0.5 moles at STP?

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry, mole

> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> $\pu{11.2 dm^3}$ of nitrogen at STP-
>
> A: has a mass of $\pu{14 g}$.
>
> B: consists of $\pu{0.5 mol}$ atoms.

My instinct was that the answer is B because any gas has a volume of $22.4$ liters regardless of what the gas is. If $\pu{0.5 mol}$ of nitrogen has a volume of $\pu{11.2 dm^3}$ at STP, then $\pu{1 mol}$ of nitrogen has a volume of $22.4$ liters at STP (if I am correct).

It turned out the answer was A. Why is B not the correct answer?

Comment: B looks like a trick answer. It would be 0.5 moles of N2 molecules but not 0.5 moles of nitrogen atoms.

Comment: So you thought B was correct, and consequently A was not correct, but did you stop to independently check whether A was correct or not?

Comment: Checkout [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mass+of+11.2+dm3+of+nitrogen+at+STP)

Comment: Subtle point.  In the 1980s the standard pressure part of STP was changed from 1 atmosphere = 101325 Pa to 1 bar = 100000 Pa.  With this reduced standard pressure the corresponding molar volume has expanded to 22.71 L.  But it seems to have been overlooked, even 30+ years on, by most texts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that 0.5 mol of $\ce{N2}$ is 11.2 L, but read the question carefully. Option B says that 11.2 L of $\ce{N2}$ contains 0.5 mol of **atoms**, which is wrong, it contains 11.2 L of $\ce{N2}$ contains 0.5 mol of **molecules**. It seems to be a trick answer. The first option is correct as 0.5 mol of $\ce{N2}$ has a mass of 14 grams.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for this question is **A**.

Prior to start explaining the answer for your question, I would like to show you a mistake you have done.
You have said

> "**any gas has a volume of 22.4 litres regardless of what the gas is.**"

This true only if the gas exist in standard temperature and pressure or (STP). And note that per one mole of any gas at STP condition occupy a volume of 22.4 litres or $22.4\ \mathrm{dm^3}$. Simply we call this as molar volume.
Here is how you can derive it.

Subject $V$ in the formula $pV=nRT$, and then you can substitute values. Where $T=273.15 \ \mathrm{K}$ (value of standard temperature) and $p=101325 \ \mathrm{Pa}$ (value of standard pressure) and $R=8.314\ \mathrm{J\ mol^{-1}\ K^{-1}}$

$$V_\mathrm{m}=\frac{V}{n}=\frac{RT}{p}$$

You have asked why not the answer B is correct?
It is not correct. Here is why:
In one mole of any compound you have $6.022\times10^{23}$ atoms

$1\ \mathrm{mol} \Rightarrow 6.022 \times 10^{23}$ atoms.

$6.022 \times 10^{23}$ is the Avogadro constant. (If you have no idea about it check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant).)
So here in this question you have found number of moles of nitrogen molecule, it means $\ce{N2(g)}$ as $0.5\ \mathrm{mol}$. Which means you have $0.5\times2\ \mathrm{mol}$ of atoms. So as I said before if you have one mole mean you already get $6.022 \times 10^{23}$ atoms of $\ce{N}$ atom. So you have $6.022 \times 10^{23}$ atoms or $6.022 \times 10^{23}$ nitrogen mol atoms. So now you can clearly see why answer B is incorrect. I hope my answer is helpful enough to solve your doubt.

Comment: The answer is not correct, in 0.5 mol of N2 you would have 6.022e23 nitrogen *atoms* and 1 mole of N atoms (if that is even a thing).

Comment: @orthocresol: Hey, as far as I know, in one mole of any compound you have 6.022e23, so how can you say " in 0.5 mol of N2 you would have 6.022e23 nitrogen atoms and 1 mole of N atoms "

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess one molecule of diatomic nitrogen has 2 nitrogen atoms

Comment: @orthocresol: It means you are saying for 1 mol  of nitrogen atom we have  6.022e23 atoms?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess yes, that is right. That is assuming that you could even have one mole of nitrogen atoms (which would, as far as I know, immediately combine to form diatomic nitrogen).

Comment: @ orthocresol: Oops, till now I have the idea in the wrong way. Because I thought , it is possible only for one mole of compound!